# Ubuntu 14.04 Quotas

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, quota

Im running a Virtual Server with Ubuntu 14.04 (in Microsoft Azure) on which I really need to make use of Quotas.

Quotas aren't currently installed, and a bit of research suggests that this was left out of the Virtual Kernels for the recent versions of Ubuntu. And this would seem to be backed up by the various errors I get which are along the lines of;

> quotaon: Quota format not supported in kernel.

Ive seen and tried several mentions of fixes including [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-user-and-group-quotas) and [this one](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/23522#comment-123848) but neither work for me. I just get the same error as above.

Interstingly(?) when I run `modprobe quota_v1` or `modprobe quota_v2` I get the following error; `modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v2 not found.`

So, any help / suggestions / ideas, as to how I can try and fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have no quota compiled into kernel - you have to build your own one. There is a guide on official site : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

NB: May be you will need .config file from original kernel to just change the options regarding quota support.